# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuetify.js

I can't figure out why this error is coming.

Another error is coming:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

This is my Vue File:

```
<v-text-field 
      label="Name *" 
      type="text"
      v-model="form.name"
      required
  >
</v-text-field>

<div v-if="errors.name">
     <span class="red--text">{{ errors.name[0] }}</span>
</div>
</v-text-field>
```

In script tag:

```
export default{
      data() {
        return {
          form: {
            name: ''
          }, 
          errors: {}
        }
      },

      methods: {
        signup(){
          axios
            .post('/api/auth/signup', this.form)
            .then(result => console.log(result.data))
            .catch(err => this.errors = err.response.data.errors)
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you share an error response. It is possible that the response doesn't have an errors key and this could be the cause for your error.

Comment: When does this error show? As soon as mounted or after `signup()`?

Comment: POST http://localhost:8000/api/auth/signup 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: When I am clicking on the submit button then it is giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

In error object there is no such property as "name" that is why is giving u the error at the time of rendering.
Also in html section do this  - > v-if="errors.name != ''"

please change the data property as -

```
export default{
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        name: ''
      }, 
      errors: {name:''}
    }
  },

  methods: {
    signup(){
      axios
        .post('/api/auth/signup', this.form)
        .then(result => console.log(result.data))
        .catch(err => this.errors.name = err.response.data.errors)
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: That is not the exact problem. Expression `{{ errors.name[0] }}` is guarded by `v-if`.